# How to get JavaScript object to properly display rectangle on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas

I'm doing an eCard for class and I have decided to create an animation using classes for the specific objects.  The first thing I am doing is trying to get the background to draw a black rectangle across the whole canvas using Background.DrawBackgound.  But nothing is working.

I have tried even copy/pasting the drawing code at the bottom to get it to draw but it will not draw.  I have done classes in C# before but am a bit rusty so I am thinking I have some error somewhere in how I've set up my classes.

Here's the .js:

```
//james gossling multimedia for web design spring 2018
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//game classes go here
Background = function() {

};
Background.prototype = {

    DrawBackground: function() {
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        context.stroke;
        context.fill;
        context.closePath();
    },


};

Confetti = function() {

};
Confetti.prototype = {



};

Firework = function() {

};
Firework.prototype = {



};

UncleSam = function() {

};
UncleSam.prototype = {



};

Text = function() {

};
Text.prototype = {



};


//other functions
var ClearScreen = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

var DrawObjects = function() {
    //ClearScreen();
    Background.DrawBackground();
};

var UpdatePositions = function(modifier) {

};

var Reset = function() {

};
//MAIN GAME LOOP FXN///////////////////
// The main game loop
var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    DrawObjects();

    UpdatePositions(delta / 1000);

    then = now;

    //possibly do RESET

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;


//START ECARD
var then = Date.now();
Background = new Background();
Reset();
main();

Background.DrawBackground();
```

and here's the .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JamesG WebDesign</title>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

<style>
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
#toMain {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    font-size: 150%;
}
#canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: thin inset #aaaaaa;
}

#ResetAboveCanvas {
            margin: 20px 0px 20px 450px;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>James Gossling Multimedia for Web Design Spring 2018 </h2>

<p><strong>4th of July eCard</strong>
</p>

<canvas id='canvas' width='600' height='800'>
Canvas not supported
</canvas>

<script src='TestPC.js'></script>

<br>
<div id="toMain">
<a href="http://webstudentwork.com/jgossling/MMWD/index.html">Back to Main</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not invoking the functions fill and stroke.invoke the fill and stroke method should fix your problem

```
DrawBackground: function() {
    console.log('here')
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.stroke(); // invoke stroke
    context.fill(); // invoke fill
    context.closePath();
},
```

Comment: i have those commands in there, i copied and pasted your code in there and there's still nothing, thank you for your help so far.  I may try removing the objects and re instituting them.

Comment: I don't know what's your case, but i tested your code and it worked for me

Comment: I tried it on my local machine and it works as well, the file I uploaded through the ftp must have just taken awhile to update, thank you for your help.